# Why was the database re-created after `flutter run --release`?

Tags: sqlite, flutter

In June, I wrote a CRUD app for my father to try and learn Flutter. I used SQLite for storing the data. I installed the app in my father's phone running `flutter run --release`.

After some months, I upgraded flutter and dependencies and started to work again on the app to add new features. (Probably irrelevant fact: I had moved from Ubuntu to Windows 10 meanwhile).

I run `flutter run --release` again on my father's phone to update the app and with my surprise the app started with no data in it (empty database). Fortunately, I had a backup of the existing database.

Now, if I run the same command, the existing database is kept as expected.

Any idea about why did the database get lost by upgrading the app from the old version?

Notes:

- I didn't touch any database-related code (no migration needed, same database version).
- The database is stored in `sqflite.getDatabasesPath()/<appName>.sqlite`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you run `flutter run --release` on another computer is actually very important. Each application is signed with a key before installation. Android SDK creates a service key for you. On different computers, the keys were different. When you install an application with a different key, the old one is completely deleted, which is what happened.